# MySQL duplicate primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, primary-key

I have a problem with the primary key:

```
Create table Information
 (
  idObject Varchar(10)not null,
  typeInfo Varchar(20)not null,
  valueInfo Varchar(1000),
  constraint key_Info PRIMARY KEY(idObject, typeInfo)
 );
```

I have a lot of information to insert in this table. One of them is Errors. It can be a few errors with the same object and type(error), so there is a conflict with the primary key.
I don't want to create an index for every information, cuz in most of cases it's unnecessary.
And how I understood, it's not possible to create an index just for several lines. How can I resolve this problem. 
Thank you!

Comment: You should revise your table structure. A column with unique values is absolutely necessary to make it 1NF. Without normalization you will be in big trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Use a surrogate primary key for the table and define a separate index for the object/type pair:

```
Create table Information (
    InformationId int not null auto_increment,
    idObject Varchar(10) not null,
    typeInfo Varchar(20)not null,
    valueInfo Varchar(1000),
    KEY(idObject, typeInfo)
);
```

You really want some sort of identifier for each row, so you can distinguish among similar rows.  This is one of the purposes of the surrogate key.  If this table is referenced by any other tables, then the surrogate key also allows for explicitly-designed foreign key relationships, a sign of good database design.

I don't know what this is supposed to mean:

> > I don't want to create an index for every information

Indexes are an integral part of the databases and should be used where appropriate.